# gif not getting displayed using php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
        console.log("mm");
        function swapContent(cv) {
            console.log("mmn");

            $("#myDiv").html('<img src="loader.gif" width="44" height="10" alt="loader.gif">').show();
            var url= "myphpscript.php";
            $.post(url, { contentVar: cv }, function(data) {
                $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
            });

            console.log("mmn");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con1');"> Content1 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con2');"> Content2 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con3');"> Content3 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <div id = "myDiv"> My Default Content 1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The gif has been saved in the same folder as the index. The divs are getting dynamically changed but the gif 'seem to get loaded. Do I need to put a delay or something and how? Or is there something else wrong with the code?

Comment: Maybe the data is loaded too fast for you to see the gif. When you remove the line `$("#myDiv").html(data).show();` do you see the gif?

Comment: please post console.log(data);

Comment: is there a way to introduce a delay?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't leave spaces in attribtue, value pairs like here:

```
...width = "44" height = "10"...
```

Make it look like this:

```
...width="44" height="10"...
```

That was just style guide :).

Second check your browsers network panel to see that:
it is loading gif. Because if there's no loading, there's no gif.
if loading that it finds it. It should return **200** http response or **404** if not found.

On all modern browsers you can open developer panel with **F12** or **CTRL+SHIFT+i** and click "Network".

Comment: it shows a 304 http response but it even showed a 200 response in some refreshes

Comment: hey i got the image working in the file load but i guesit is loading it pretty fast ,is therea way to introduce a delay in the page load?

Comment: Why should you need a delay? :)

Comment: because i wish to display the animation before the divs change?

Comment: jQuery has .delay() which you can use like this: $(image).show().delay(2000).hide() which will show, delay 2secs and hide

Comment: and does the image parameter can be a .gif?

Comment: parameter must be DOM element, so your <img> element holding gif